# Is there a way to delete all log entries in a file older than a certain date? (BASH)

Tags: bash, date, ubuntu, logging

I have log file in which I'm trying to delete all entries older than a specified date. Though I haven't succeeded with this yet. What I've tested so far is having an input for what the entries must be older than to be deleted and then loop like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

COUNTER=7
DATE=$(date -d "-${COUNTER} days" +%s)
DATE=$(date -d -@${DATE} "+%Y-%m-%d")

while [ -n "$(grep $DATE test.txt)" ]; do

    sed -i "/$DATE/d" test.txt

    COUNTER=$((${COUNTER}+1))
    DATE=$(date -d "-${COUNTER} days" +%s)
    DATE=$(date -d @${DATE} +"%Y-%m-%d")
done
```

This kind of works except when a log entry doesn't exist for date. When it doesn't find a match it aborts the loop and the even older entries are kept.

**Update**

This was how I solved it:

```
#!/bin/bash

COUNTER=$((7+1))
DATE=$(date -d "-${COUNTER} days" +%s)
DATE=$(date -d -@${DATE} "+%Y-%m-%d")

if [ -z "$(grep $DATE test.txt)" ]; then
   exit 1
fi

sed -i "1,/$DATE/d" test.txt
```

Comment: You should be able to do this using `find` and `-mtime`.

Comment: I think he means each log line in a file has an associated datetime, and that we wants to remove specific lines from the log file.

Comment: Have you considered using `logrotate` instead?

Comment: if it's some kind of log file you're deleting entries from, would it be a safe assumption that all entries are appended to the end of the file, and that the timestamp of each new entry is greater than the last one? If so, you could probably just iterate through the file and remove all entries until you find a timestamp that matches (or is greater than) your desired date.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Martin Frost! I will try that approach! :)

Comment: Martin if you post your idea as an answer I will mark it as the accepted one. It worked wonders

Comment: Regarding your solution: be careful, it works, **BUT** if the $DATE could not be found in your log file, it will clear out the whole file!

Comment: Thanks Zsolt, I realised that too while testing and added a check for this. I've updated the post with this now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for answering my own question but I went with Martin Frost's suggestion in the comments. It was much easier than the other suggestions.

This was my implementation:

```
#!/bin/bash

# requirements for script script

COUNTER=$((7+1))
DATE=$(date -d "-${COUNTER} days" +%s)
DATE=$(date -d -@${DATE} "+%Y-%m-%d")

sed -i "1,/$DATE/d" test.txt
```

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: or as one-liner:

sed -i "1,/$(date -d "8 day ago" '+%F')/d" test.txt

Comment: this might delete entire file, if there was no line with $DATE in it

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your logfile format, assuming that the timestamp is the first column in the file you can do it like this with `(g)awk`.

```
awk 'BEGIN { OneWeekEarlier=strftime("%Y-%m-%d",systime()-7*24*60*60) }
     $1 <= OneWeekEarlier { next }
     1' INPTUTLOG > OUTPUTLOG
```

This computes the date - surprise, surprise - one week earlier, then checks if the first column (white space separated columns by default) is less than or equal, and if true, skips the line, otherwise prints.

The *hard* part is doing the *"in place"* editing with awk. But it can be done:

```
{ rm LOGFILE && awk 'BEGIN { OneWeekEarlier=strftime("%Y-%m-%d",systime()-7*24*60*60) }
     $1 <= OneWeekEarlier { next }
     1' > LOGFILE ; } < LOGFILE
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I went with Martin Frost's suggestion, it was much easier to do this operation with sed.

Comment: See my comment above regarding your solution!

Answer (score 1):

I deleted log records in syslog-ng files before 60 days ago with following code.

```
#!/bin/bash   

LOGFILE=/var/log/syslog    
DATE=`date +"%b %e" --date="-60days"`    
sed -i "/$DATE/d" $LOGFILE
```

Comment: This seems to remove only the logs created exactly 60 days ago, but not those created 61 or more days ago